# TikZ: Declare Function vs Macro: use of cm

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, automata, positioning, matrix, calc}
\usepackage[RPvoltages, american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}[H]\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture} [declare function = {buffHeight = 5; vertDis = 2;}] 
            \def\buffHeight{5};
            \def\vertDis{2};
            \draw(0,0) node[draw, minimum width = 1.25cm, minimum height = \buffHeight] (Samp1){}; 
            \draw(\vertDis,0) node[draw, minimum width = 1.25cm, minimum height = \buffHeight] (Samp2){};
            \draw(0,-6) node[draw, minimum width = 1.25cm, minimum height = buffHeight] (Samp3){};
            \draw(vertDis,-6) node[draw, minimum width = 1.25cm, minimum height = buffHeight] (Samp4){};
        \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

`\vertDis` and `vertDis` gave me the same results as well as `\buffHeight` and `buffHeight`. But when I put in `cm` for the macro and the variable version i.e. `\vertDis cm` and `vertDis cm`, the former worked, while the latter gave me an error. Why does the macro version work with `cm`, but not the non-macro version?

Comment: you need braces otherwise tikz cannot make out the start and end points

Comment: So like `{vertDis} cm`?

Comment: I actually tried that, but it didn’t work. Can you show me how it’s actually done?

Comment: I wonder if `vertDis*1cm` works.

Comment: That worked! Interesting, I wonder why.

Comment: So keys like `minimum height` will throw its argument into `\pgfmathsetlength` or a similar macro (so that users can input `1cm + 1in*3`). But mixing functions and units confuses it. So better separate them by operators. (BTW, `\vertDis` will be faster than `vertDis`; so I always stick to the former.)

Comment: Why is `\vertDis` faster than `vertDis`? Also, besides `minimum height`, what about the coordinates like `\vertDis`?

Comment: The general idea is that macro-constants, like `\def\a{1.41421}` and `\pgfmathsetmacro\b{sqrt(2)}` are expanded by TeX itself and is fast. On the other hand, a nullary function will undergo PGF's math engine, which is some heavy string-parsing stuff. For coordinates, such as `(2, 3)`, they undergo another family of macros (`\tikz@scan@one@point` etc). A way to distinguish them is that, while the default unit for `line width` is `pt`; the default unit of coordinates is `cm`.

Comment: Interesting, what do you mean by “nullary” by the way. Can you clarify that adjective?

Comment: A nullary (0-ary) function is a function that takes 0 arguments. In (at least) mathematical logic, constants are treated as nullary functions to unify the terminology.

Comment: if you don't provide a unit for tikz arguments like height and width, you may get lucky or you may not.  I try not to rely on luck.