# TikZ: Declare Function vs Macro: Dimensions

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

This query is based on [this.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/566324/204403)

`buffHeight` and `vertDis`’s dimensions are in pt. What about macro-defined constants (`\buffHeight` and `\vertDis`)? Are they unitless? If so, if I slap in a unit, i.e., `\buffHeight cm`, would it give me 5 cm, and `\buffHeight in` 5 inches?

Comment: Macros expand to their definition as they are encountered by the expansion processor, i.e. `\buffHeight cm` will become a literal `1cm`.

Comment: And likewise, if I put `in` instead of `cm`, the macro’s dimensions will be in inches instead of centimeters.

Comment: Yes, there are also a couple of other units you can use.  There is a list here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/

Comment: Oh ok. By the way, if I don’t specify the units for the macro, are the macro’s units set to `pt` by default? I.e. just saying `minimum height = \buffHeight` would give `\buffHeight` pt

Comment: No, a macro doesn't have units.  It just expands to its literal value.  What you are referring to is `\pgfsetlength` which is an entirely different story because it implements its own parser.  In this context dimensionless numbers are implicitly assigned `pt` but that is very different from TeX's normal dimension parsing.  For example `\parindent=1` would raise an error whereas `\pgfmathsetlength{\parindent}{1}` would assign `1pt`.

Comment: Oh, so would the line `minimum height = \buffHeight` when setting up the shape’s dimensions raise an error?

Comment: No, because that is parsed with `\pgfmathsetlength` (like most things in TikZ), so `\buffHeight` expands to a literal `1` which receives an implicit `pt`.

Comment: Oh, it’s done in the backend for the aforementioned case. Interesting.